# Simple Java Program to concat two strings with overlapping

Tags: java

I am working on this college project that develops a hybrid algorithm using Genetic Algo and Bee Colony Optimization. I am stuck at a small problem.

Let us assume we have two strings:

```
String x="001100110011";

String y="001101110110";
```

I need to form a new string that combines both x and y by superimposing them.

```
String out="001101110111";
```

I tried using an algorithm I found here on StackOverflow but couldn't get the desired result.

```
public String docat(String f, String s) {
        if (!f.contains(s.substring(0,1)))
            return f + s;
        int idx = s.length();
        try {
            while (!f.endsWith(s.substring(0, idx--))) ;
        } catch (Exception e) { }
        return f + s.substring(idx + 1);
    }
```

My goal is to keep on concatenating strings until I reach 111111111111. The length is fixed at 12.

Comment: Why do you use a String to represent 12 bits? Use BitSet, which is much more logical, more efficient, and has the method you need (`or()`).

Comment: You could also use a primitive like `short` or `int` and use the bitwise operation `|`

Comment: I have to make it as simple as possible using only the stuff we have been taught yet. And thanks a ton mate :) I can use OR operator.

Comment: And you haven't been taught to use the best type for the task and read API documentation?

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't know genetic algorithms, but it is not really clear how it is that you intend to combine those two binary strings to get the third one. String x="001100110011";

String y="001101110110"; String out="001101110111";  Your out string looks like y, but with the last digit as 1. What's the algorithm that you want?

Comment: @barlop the 1 represents a fault covered and 0 represents not covered. each string is a test case. I need to find the minimum number of test cases that can cover all faults. So, in the above example, x covers 6 faults out of 12, y covers 7 out of 12 and the output will have all the faults of x and y.

Comment: @JBNizet sir, I know I have not done my research on this.. But if you were in my college, you would be doing exactly the same thing

Comment: You have done your research, since you asked here. But when told that there is a much better tool than the one you're using, that's where you should learn how to use the better tool, and not stick with the one you have. I don't see why I would do the same as you're doing. I've never been taught Java and tons of other tools at school, yet I use them every day. You'd better learn to read documentation, because most of the tools you will use in your career won't be taught at school, simply because they don't even exist yet.

Comment: I do get it and am reading about BitSet class now. Will definitely use it from this point onwards as need be.

Comment: You said an answer somebody gave, is what you wanted, but theirs didn't involve concatenation, and your question said you want to concatenate strings.  Maybe you are using words that you don't know the meaning of.  Concatenate means that if you have a string of 5 characters and a string of 4 characters, the resulting concatenated string would be 5+4=9 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String doIt(String x, String y)
{
    return Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(x, 2) | Integer.parseInt(y, 2));

}
```

this works for what you are aiming to do and mostly relates to your code.

(edit: you may need to format the string to ensure all 12 digits are there)

Comment: This is a bit twisted and a way to go only if you are stuck with the Strings for some reason.

Comment: @AlexErohin I was assuming that here, as he mentioned above he has to stick with what he knows.

Comment: can you elaborate on "a bit twisted"? what'd you have done?

Answer (score -1):

If your lenth is fixed at 12, and all you have to do is OR the two strings
then just go:

```
String orStr (String s1, String s1)
{
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<12; ++i)
    {
       if (s1.charAt(i)=='1' || s2.charAt(i)=='1')
       {
           result += "1";
        } else {
           result +="0";
        }
     }
     return result;
}
```

but why should you keep bits in a String?

Comment: Please at least use a StringBuilder.

Comment: that is a lot of unnecessary braces. Certainly the if else doesn't gain more clarity from the superfluous braces

Comment: You haven't addressed the fact that the title of his question mentions concatenate and (rightly or wrongly), your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @barlop a lot of people advocate always using braces, not for clarity but for maintainability concerns : a newbie that would like to add a line to your else block might forget to add braces, while if they're already here all he has to do is add his line. I do not personally agree with this idea, but I don't think we should mind the extra braces either